# Java book was unclear on these two topics

Tags: java

The basic components of a class: 
Is that they can be thought of as templates from which objects can be made?

Three things you can assign to a numeric variable:
Are they: Constants, numbers other variables.

Thanks! I'm trying to pick up the basics, but these two topics from my book have no clear cut answer just a header with an example.

Comment: I can't understand what you don't understand and what you do understand.

Comment: you should ask specific questions...

Answer (score 2):

1)I think you have the right idea, but really bad terminology.  A class is an object that consists of some data and some code.  You can create an instance of a class (called instantiating the class).  Each instance has its own copy of all non-static variables in the class.

2)You can assign a number to a numeric variable.  Yes, that number could be a constant, another variable, or some mathematical combination of other variables (like x+y, or 5+10, or 15*z).  Or a numeric result of a function (say Math.max(x,y) which returns the bigger of x and y).